# how to advanced text adjust in html?

Tags: html

Is it possible in html/and if so how?
I want to make something like:

Text

(10x space)Text"br"text

How to make it happen, as for current knowledge only possibility seen "left center right"

**SOLVED**

...........was in between..............

solution of &nbsp **correct**, however its unperfect:

1. As it would take huge amounts of spaces to adjust to long sentences especially,
2. separate spaces after "br" would be needed as well.

any better solutions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50s0c.png

...........................

padding not worked, is it is only for css? Or did i wrote it bad?
`<P><padding-left> Music/Memes<BR>Lectures..</padding-left></P>`

Comment: You can try `padding-left`.

Comment: As stated in the comment above, the `padding` rule can be used. tell me more specifically what you want and I will give you a solution. The solution with `&nbsp;` can be used, but it is not perfect today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use HTML Entity:**   `&nbsp;` for spaces in HTML.

e.g.,

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; Hello World</p>
```

**UPDATE:**
We also have Other spacing entities in HTML: In case you want play around.

1. `&emsp;`—the em space; this should be a very wide space, typically as
   much as four real spaces.
2. `&ensp;`—the en space; this should be a somewhat wide space, roughly
   two regular spaces.
3. `&thinsp;`—this will be a narrow space, even more narrow than a regular
   space.

However, if you require a lots of spacing I recommend using CSS `padding` and `margins` as per your requirement. :) If you do not want to use a CSS file. You can do inline-style as shown below:

**CODE DEMO:**

```html
<div style="padding-left:16px">Music Memes</div>
<div>Lectures...</div>
```

And yes coming to your last statement. Yes indeed `<P><padding-left> Music/Memes<BR>Lectures..</padding-left></P>`, this is not the right way to do it :)

Comment: Would it be possible to make it something like 10x&nbsp?

Comment: Not in HTML. But If you use &emsp; This would be 4*&nbsp; This is the highest we have.This follows ems. And &ensp; would be roughly two spaces.

Comment: If you use &emsp;&emsp;&ensp; This will make your 10*&nbsp; Give it a try :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. To help you more. In case you want more spaces and other margin. Best is to use CSS padding and margins. Do Vote  on the answer if my update has helped you :) Thank you. Need any other help I am only only. Working on a Project :)

Comment: I am a bit needy in that sense, of shortening code, anyway, really appreciate your answers.

Comment: I just saw your Image. And code you have written in your Question. In case you want specific spacing. You can use padding left. Even in inline style like <p style="padding-left:10px">Music Memes</>

Comment: @TimerTak : I have updated my answer. I have used inline-style. Try this. I think this may also be helpful along with HTML entities :)

Comment: That just perfect! Thank you, once again.

Comment: cannot give vote, as I’m newbie still here, will defiantly give it in future.

Comment: Sure Dear Friend :) I have voted on your question to encourage you to never quit coding. Best  wishes from myside for your Coding Journey :)